# vfp query much faster in command window than compiled

Tags: sql, t-sql, query-optimization, visual-foxpro, command-window

Here's my query:

```
SELECT solGroup,;
       SUM(IIF((;
                SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cgift c2;
                    WHERE c2.solgroup != c1.solgroup AND c1.donor == c2.donor;
                ) > 0;
           ,1,0));
        countgaveother;
    FROM cgift c1;
    GROUP BY solGroup
```

cGift is a cursor containing a list of records.

```
autonumber...donor....solGroup
1............10.......a
2............11.......a
3............10.......b
4............15.......b
5............10.......c
6............15.......c
7............11.......d
8............11.......d
9............16.......d
```

The query generates the following

```
solGroup.."count of donors who have records with a different solgroup as well as this one"
a..........2
b..........2
c..........2
d..........1
```

There are about 80k records in cGift (and many more fields that are not used here). It takes 3 seconds to run this query (plus the one creating the cursor) from the vfp command window and 30 minutes to run from inside a compiled form.

Anyone have any idea why the performance difference is so great? Normally the command window performs very similar to my compiled forms. Other queries run perfectly fine in this form as well.

The cursor is created with a `select ... into cursor cGift`. It is ordered by donor, though removing this changes nothing.

I'm on VFP 9 sp2. Anyone know how speed it up?

EDIT:
Ok, let me summarize and see if anyone else has any ideas.
I create a cursor with a `select into ... cursor cGift`.
Then I run the above query on said cursor.
It's fast in the command window but very slow when running from a form.
Exact same code for both cursor and query.
I have no idea what environment settings are on/off/wtvr in my form since it's part of a very large program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i couldn't figure out what was different in the two enviorments but i sped the query up by changing it and breaking into two parts (something is wrong the with the sql engine if queries run faster after being broken apart...)

```
SELECT *;
    FROM cgift;
    LEFT JOIN;
         (select donor donor2, count(distinct solgroup) activesols from cGift group by donor);
    b ON cgift.donor = b.donor2 INTO CURSOR cgift
```

Then i count where activesol > 1

Merging those makes everything very slow.

Comment: But it looks like you restructured as well. I'm not surprised that a query with a derived table would be faster than one with a projection.

Answer (score 2):

What's different in the application than in the Command window? Here are some possibilities:

- SET ANSI and/or SET EXACT
- SET DELETED
- the set of indexes available (if you're actually addressing different tables)
- the code page and/or collation sequence

There are probably some others, but my guess is it's one or more of those.

Tamar

Comment: I'm not sure what code page/collation sequence is but the others aren't working, including LAK's inputs. Indexing shouldn't be a problem since i create a cursor right before the query and that's the only table the query uses. The cursor is created with exactly the same code in both command window and form.

Comment: It's the lack of indexes that's making it slow in both environments. (3 seconds for a query is slow in the VFP world.) Something must be different between the two environments to give you an order of magnitude difference, too.

Answer (score 1):

I concur that it's probably something about your Command box environment vs. the environment of your executing program.  I'd add the SHARED/EXCLUSIVE state of the tables, and/or the setting of SET('EXCLUSIVE') to the list of things to check.